# State monad - adapt functions that only work with parts of the state?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, state, monads

I have a general state which is essentially a 3-tuple, and a number of functions which each concern themselves with parts of that state.  I'm trying to work out a set of generic adapters for such functions, so that I can use them in a State monad pipeline.

This is possibly entirely wrongheaded; feel free to make that case.

I apologize in advance for mix of Java and pidgin Scala.  I'm actually doing this in Java as a learning exercise, but nobody has time to read all that.  I've elided a lot of uninteresting complexity for the sake of discussion; don't worry about the domain modeling.

The state in question is this:

```
ImportState(row:CsvRow, contact:Contact, result:ImportResult)
```

`ImportResult` is one of `ADD`, `MERGE`, or `REJECT`.

The functions I've defined are these:

```
def rowToContact: ImportRow => Contact

def findMergeCandidates: Contact => (Contact, List[Contact])

// merges, or declines to merge, setting the result
def merge: (Contact, List[Contact]) => (Contact, ImportResult)  

def persist: Contact => ImportResult

def commitOrRollback: ImportState => ImportState

def notifyListener: ImportState => Nothing
```

The adapters I've defined so far are pretty simple, and deal with individual properties of `ImportState`:

```
def getRow: ImportState => ImportRow

def getContact: ImportState => Contact

def setRow(f: _ => ImportRow): ImportState => ImportState

def setContact(f: _ => Contact): ImportState => ImportState

def setResult(f: _ => ImportResult): ImportState => ImportState
```

The (broken) pipeline looks something like this (in Java):

```
State.<ImportState>init()
    .map( setRow( constant(row) ) )
    .map( setContact( getRow.andThen(rowToContact) ) )
    .map( getContact.andThen(findMergeCandidates).andThen(merge) ) // this is where it falls apart
    .map( setResult( getContact.andThen(persist) ) )
    // ... lots of further processing of the persisted contact
    .map(commitOrRollback)
    .map(notifyListener);
```

The immediate problem is that `merge` returns a tuple `(Contact, ImportResult)`, which I'd like to apply to two properties of the state (`contact` and `result`), while keeping the third property, `row`.

So far, I've come up with a couple of approaches to adaptation of merge that both suck:

1. Define some functions that pack and unpack tuples, and use them directly in the pipeline.  This option is extremely noisy.
2. Define a one-off adapter for `ImportState` and `merge`.  This option feels like giving up.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is tagged Haskell - I'm hoping that means you can read Haskell, and not that someone saw 'monads' and added it.  On that assumption, I'll be speaking Haskell in this answer, since it's the language I think in these days ;)

There's a useful concept called "functional lenses" with a couple Haskell library implementations.  The core idea is that a "lens" is a pair of functions:

```
data Lens a b = Lens { extract :: (a -> b), update :: (a -> b -> a) }
```

This represents a functional way of getting and updating "parts" of a structure.  With a type like this, you can write a function such as:

```
subState :: Lens a b -> State a t -> State b t
subState lens st = do
    outer <- get
    let (inner, result) = runState st (extract lens outer)
    put (update lens outer inner)
    return result
```

Translating that into Java sounds like an interesting (and possibly quite challenging) exercise!

Comment: Thanks!  I tagged it Haskell because I can more or less read Haskell, with the aid of a Haskell-English dictionary.

Comment: This looks like it pairs up my get/set functions.  For a state with n fields, is there a Haskell idiom for composing extract and update functions so that you don't need n^2-1 of each?

Comment: @loganj: yes, in the fclabels package for example, the lens type is an instance of "Data.Category.Category", which means it defines an "identity lens" `id :: Lens a a` and a "lens composition" `(.) :: Lens b c -> Lens a b -> Lens a c`. The definition is pretty straightforward - the new get is just the composition of the old ones, and with an auxiliary function `modify :: Lens a b -> (b -> b) -> a -> a`., the new 'set' is something like: `modify lens1 outer (\inner -> update lens2 inner x)`.  This is kinda ugly due to my choice of argument order in `update`, but hopefully it makes sense anyway.

Comment: @loganj: or it occurs to me you might have wanted a "horizontal" composition such as "pair :: Lens a b -> Lens a c -> Lens a (b,c)"?  There is something like that in the fclabels package too.  I would recommend looking through the source of that package, it's a pretty good read and introduces a lot of potentially useful idioms.

Comment: the "horizontal" composition is exactly what I'm after.  Thanks, I'll go dig through fclabels.  See, this is why I tagged it haskell... I knew a Haskell programmer would have the answer!

Comment: @mokus, if someone else had come along and tagged the message `haskell`, you'd see a name to the left of loganj's name after the post, and you could click it to see a revision history and know exactly who added the haskell tag. (Kinda like how Daniel came along and edited your answer).

Comment: @Ken Bloom, thanks for the explanation.  I wasn't entirely sure how it would be displayed, but it makes sense that it would appear as an "edit" of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting I wrote this exact operation last night using fclabels:

```
withGame :: (r :-> r', s :-> s') -> GameMonad r' s' a -> GameMonad r s a
withGame (l1,l2) act = do
    (r,s) <- (,) <$> askM l1 <*> getM l2
    (a, s') <- liftIO $ runGame r s act
    setM l2 s'
    return a
```

GameMonad is a new type that is a monad transformer stack of state, reader, IO. I'm also using a bit of applicative functor style code don't let it put you off, it's pretty much the same as mokus.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at replacing the tuple approach with case classes. You get a lot for free in a structure that is virtually as easy to define, in particular a compiler generated copy method which allows you to create a copy of an instance, changing only the fields you want to change.